# Take the biggest size of a div and make all of them the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to take the biggest image height from the page and make all the images at same height by using images placeholders or something, also to be responsive: desktop / mobile / table

Most important, we speak about images. I have an image with 600px height and another one with 300px height.
Lets take this scenario:

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="600">
    <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="200">
    <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="350">
    <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="450">
    <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="350">
    <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="150">
    <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="350">
    <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="350">
    <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="550">
    <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="350">
</div>
```

In this scenario, I want to check entire page for the biggest height and put it on all images as a transparent background with the main image in the middle.
I don't have nothing did on this because I don't know what to do and I kindly ask for help here. Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the images responsive for Desktop, Mobile, Tablet, you could set the width to use `65vw` instead of `350px`.

Example:

```
<img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Googlelogo.png" alt="" style="width:50vw">
```

I think you could do something with JavaScript to search through each image's properties to find the biggest image height.. Or if you set it yourself that would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use background images and a nested div to set the aspect ratio.

```css
#images .image {
width: 350px; 
max-width: calc(50% - 5px);
float: left;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
display: inline-block; 
background-color: black;
background-position: center center;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#images .image div {padding-top: 100%;}
```

```html
<div id="images">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://jekyllcodex.org/uploads/grumpycat.jpg);"><div></div></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://jekyllcodex.org/uploads/grumpycat2.jpg);"><div></div></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://jekyllcodex.org/uploads/grumpycat.jpg);"><div></div></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://jekyllcodex.org/uploads/grumpycat2.jpg);"><div></div></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://jekyllcodex.org/uploads/grumpycat.jpg);"><div></div></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://jekyllcodex.org/uploads/grumpycat2.jpg);"><div></div></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://jekyllcodex.org/uploads/grumpycat.jpg);"><div></div></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://jekyllcodex.org/uploads/grumpycat2.jpg);"><div></div></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://jekyllcodex.org/uploads/grumpycat.jpg);"><div></div></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://jekyllcodex.org/uploads/grumpycat2.jpg);"><div></div></div>
</div>
```